# Image getSize for secured api endpoints (use authorization)

Tags: react-native

I want to get the size of remote images to scale them correctly. 
I used Image.getSize to do that but now my api has also some secured endpoints which expects an access token.
The getSize function only takes a string for the uri and nothing else.

So how do I get the dimensions of a remote image where I need to set an access token?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the `Image.getSize` method only takes a String URL and there is no way to pass any request / connection parameters. Unfortunately I think you're out of luck.

You might need to look at the source for that class/method and write your own implementation which does take a request object.